# JAVA Display both JOPTIONPANE messages as one message

Tags: java, joptionpane

I need this to show as one Joptionpane, NOT one then the other.  However, the second contains information from a textarea and will not show up correctly when I put it with the first.  How do I go about this?   The "Per" shows multiple textfields and combobox answers.  The ContactTA is a textarea.

```
                for (int count = 0; count < per.size(); count++){
                //contactTA.add(per.get(count).toString());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, per.get(count).toString());
            }
              JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(main, contactPanel,
                    "Contact Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: The second doesn't have to be a confirm dialog, it was just the only way I could get it to show the textarea entry.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be trying to merge two different JOptionPanes? I would recommend just making your own error message class depending on what you are trying to do. If you really want both messages up at the same time I believe you can do it with threading.